# DB Unit cannot select MsSQL NVARCHAR data type

Tags: dbunit

DBUnit can select all columns of MsSQL database table except NVARCHAR type.
When I select value of NVARHCAR type column, it throws 
`org.dbunit.dataset.NoSuchColumnException: <table name>.<column name>`

Here is my code;

```
    protected IDatabaseConnection getConnection() throws Exception {
      Class driverClass = Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
      Connection jdbcConnection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=<dbName>;selectMethod=cursor", "sa", "sa");
      return new DatabaseConnection(jdbcConnection);
    }

    public void test() {
       IDataSet databaseDataSet = getConnection().createDataSet();
       ITable actualTable = databaseDataSet.getTable("Table");
       actualTable.getValue(0, "Description"); // throws exception here. 'Description' is NVARCHAR
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

When I use driver of JNetDirect JSQLConnect rather than Microsoft JDBC driver, it recognize NVARCHAR.
But it is free for a single user with only 1 database connection.
I found it from [here](http://dbunit.wikidot.com/mssql)